# Prevent status bar from receiving touch events

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

**Edit**

After further testing, it appears that the part of my button that are not clickable are where the status bar used to be. I'm hiding the status bar with :

```
// -- Override point for customization after app launch    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Also added the Boolean value to my *-info.plist file:

```
UIStatusBarHidden=true
```

Which is awesome because it hides the status bar even as the window animates up. But it's still receiving touches. Any idea on how to disable this?

---

**Original Post**

Is there's a bounding box on an application that receives touch events? I created a few sample round rect buttons and placed them in different places in my view. The ones in the center of the view receive touch events (and show the highlighted blue color) but if I place a button near the edges of the view, only parts of them are clickable in the simulator. Is this because of Apples style guidelines? I placed a button exactly where a UITabNavigationItem would appear and only the bottom half of it is clickable.

Comment: It's more likely that you are not properly sizing your view. The statusbar doesn't take any events when it is hidden.

Comment: My view fills the entire 480, and I can see the button fine at 0, 0. Would I even see anything rendered there if my view wasn't scaled properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simulator has a bug with clickability of the former status bar area. Test on the real device.

Comment: I saw this but I also saw people saying it was a bug on the device. I have to upgrade my XCode to test on my device, but will try tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed that my application works fine on the device, not in simulator. Thanks!